# what is the difference between .component.html and .html in angular2 templateUrl

Tags: angular

Started working on Angular2 and I found curious about the following code:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: `example.component.html`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'John'; }
```

vs

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `example.html`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'John'; }
```

what is the .component.html in that?

Comment: just naming convention., it's up to you to add `.component` or not.

Comment: See style guide https://angular.io/styleguide#!#-a-id-05-04-a-extract-templates-and-styles-to-their-own-files

Answer (score 1):

- Both are same, angular will add `.component` just to differentiate that it is component.
- It is juts a name of your template in the folder, its upto you whether to add `.component` or add if you are creating component manually.
- If you are creating component using command line angular will `.component` in your component name automatically.

> Do give the filename the conventional suffix (such as .component.ts, .directive.ts, .module.ts, .pipe.ts, or .service.ts) for a file of that type.

see here for more info

- https://angular.io/styleguide

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing ,

Just for our understadning , we can use both `demo.component.html/demo.html` ,
but there are some guides for files names , variables name , as a standard practice ,

For more detail you should resd this : [Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide)